# Awaken after millions of years of spacetravel, what day is today, what time it is and to where should I look at?

Tags: space-travel, religion, time-keeping

Bob is a 30 years old man who has a religion, called Bobism that is a particular blend of Judaism, Islamism, Christianism, Buddhism, Madeupism and Wtfism. Bob is a strict rigorous practizer of Bobism.

Bobism is a religion that tells its practizers to:

1. No work whatsoever should be performed on Saturdays.
2. Celebrate Easter and Christmas.
3. Pray facing Mecca.
4. Do not eat at night during Ramadan.
5. Pray at noon every day.
6. Commemorate the Chinese new year.
7. Commemorate Vesak in the first full moon day of May.
8. The only way to get forgiven for not correctly following the laws 1 to 7 is to commit immediate suicide.
9. People frozen up, in deep sleep, fainted, in coma, dead or otherwise unable to make conscious decisions are exempted from the need to obey the laws 1 to 8.

Bob is about to be frozen, put into a spaceship and sent far away into deep space. The ship will travel to somewhere at least with >95% of the lightspeed for an unspecified amount of time somewhere in the order of several millions of years (measured in spaceship's reference frame). Then, at some moment, the spaceship's IA will decide to unfroze and wake up him.

There are few guarantees whatsoever of where he will be when he wakes up. He could just be landed on an exoplanet (and if this is the case, the IA will decelerate and land orderly and safely). It could be a planet full or life. Or perhaps, full of lava. Or maybe, full of ice. Or full of arsenic, hydrogen sulfide, hydrofluoric acid and cyanide. Or just a dull boring cold rock with no atmosphere. Or possibly, the ship doesn't land anywhere at all and it will be spinning rapidly around its own axis taking only a few seconds to complete a turn in the middle of interstellar space with no recognizable stars visible anywhere.

There is one guarantee, however: If/when he wakes up, he won't be dead, so this means that the ship didn't flung into the core of a star, nor into a black hole nor was blown to bits in some collision, did not self-destructed, nor was disintegrated by the megablaster-ray of an alien civilization nor anything like that.

The ship is able to provide him air, food, water, shower, toilet, medicines and a clean space to live for tens of millions of years, if he lives that far enough, without ever needing to venture outside. The ship also provides a standard 110 volts and 60 Hz electricity power line to plug any equipment that needs electricity. However, it is just that and nothing more. There is no wi-fi, no internet, nor even a paper calendar nor a wall clock.

The freezing procedure happens in a few seconds, just like Han Solo was frozen up in carbonite in Star Wars. The unfreezing is quick too and very harmless (no temporary blindness like to Han Solo). Bob might be a bit confused when he awakens, but surely, in no more than say, 5 minutes, he would be fully aware of what happened and perfectly capable of doing conscious decisions.

The IA don't ever talk to Bob or listen him and is entirely autonomous. It treats him like most people would treat a pet fish in an aquarium. I.e. no useful communication is stablished or even tried to be stablished and it just tries its best to provide an environment for the pet to live healthy.

Bob is allowed to take 1000 kg of personal equipment with him, have one million dollars available to purchase that equipment and have just a week before the launch. But he only might get hands to that equipment onboard after he is awaked, so he can't setup anything for him before the launch.

Bob wants to live as long as possible, die of old age (i.e., more than 80 years old discounting the time he was frozen) and never commit suicide (law 8), but his life is meaningless if he does not strict follows his religion. When he wakes up, what can he do in order to actually correctly follow his religion? When he awakens, is there a way to tell or even to meaningful define what day is today or what time is it now? What should he bring in as his equipment?

And, if you think that this is unsolvable and suicide is inevitable, what is the smallest change that you could do into the spaceship or into laws 1 to 7 of Bobism (creating Neobobism) in order to make this solvable?

---

Or, to keep it simple, it all comes down to this: **Is there a way to measure Earthly-time and directions when you are completely lost in space or in some other unknown planet?**

Comment: Can you up the allowance? Because then you can do something with atomic clocks. They measure minute chances in atoms, like electromagnetic radiation. This is a very regular occurance, allowing these clocks to be the most precise and long living clocks in existence, though you might want to use multiple for redundancy. With further gyroscopes, accelerometers and such you can come close, but if it needs to survive millions of years it'll need to be expensive grade A equipment.

Comment: "_several millions of years_" do you mean years of _ship_ (or [proper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time)) time, or years of _Earth_ (or [coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_time)) time? When you're travelling at .95c+ there's a big difference between the two.

Comment: @Trioxidane Put that into an answer. If there is no way to solve without this stuff, so be it. But I will also wait to see more creative or clever answers. Also, even with all that equipment, it is still not so easy, I guess, so I would like to see your answer.

Comment: @StarfishPrime Figuring out that is part of the problem. I put the >95% lightspeed part with the exact purpose of creating a problem with the twin paradox.

Comment: @StarfishPrime Anyway, it is a veeeeery long time when Bob awakens and he has no idea where he is, nor where Earth is nor how much time it passed exactly or even approximatelly.

Comment: @VictorStafusa uh, no. This isn't a puzzle-game site; we shouldn't have to guess what you mean. Did millions of years pass on board the ship?

Comment: @StarfishPrime Yes. Millions of years passed on the spaceship.

Comment: You seem to be setting conditions deliberately so that Bob cannot determine location/time under any circumstances, and then asking us to knock down that straw man. That does seem like a puzzle more than worldbuilding. The "minimum change" wiggle is also common in puzzles.

Comment: @user535733 It simply comes down to this: is there a way to measure Earthly-time and directions when you are completely lost in space or in some other planet?

Comment: @VictorStafusa can you measure earthly-time and directions when you are completely lost __on Earth__ either underground or on a cloudy day or during a snowstorm etc? You need an external reference point _even_ on Earth, and you have removed it for Bob.

Comment: @EveryBitHelps This is why Bob could bring up your equipment to help him. If Bob is underground on Earth, but has an atomic clock, a working GPS receiver or some other complex stuff, he could figure it out. And if after that, he finds out that it is not Saturday, he would be fine.

Comment: I feel sorry for all those cavers who practise Bobism. Caving with an atomic clock must be _fun_.

Comment: I don't think Bobism can survive very long as a religion. It has no allowances for IRL incidents which would cause nearly all practioners to commit immediate suicide the minute they make a mistake due to no fault of their own.

Comment: This need not be about religion requiring absolute facts. Bob would always be lost.  I think this is a question with anthropological ties as well. I'm not going along with the vtc, I tried to answer it.

Comment: 4 and 5 are strictly impossible to solve in a consistent manner if Earth time is desired as a referent.  You might be able to say, "It's the 4th of November" to a reasonably accurate degree, but "it's noon on Earth" is always trueish.

Comment: The answer to this question is "no", after the edit. Because the opener was forced into changing it into a physics question. Closers are regarding these rules as 100% Earth-bound. This guy has traveled million light years. There are no references, he just wants to perform religious duties.. god  is perceived as traveling with him, the new habitat provides a "noon", not Earth. You're right about 4, because it is bound to a specific calendar, like Eastern. But the other times can be derived when Bob finds his planet.  To find Mecca, or decide when Ramadan will start, the gods provide a sign.

Comment: I VTC'ed because this feels on all sides more like a puzzle than a worldbuilding question. Those qualifiers of 1000 kg of equipment worth 1 million dollars feel like "what would you take to a deserted island"; how is this a matter of establishing rules and systems for a world?

Comment: @Goodies. I really appreciate your answer BTW. It is very informative.

Comment: @EveryBitHelps Originally, I would put three persons in the spaceship, each one with a different real-world religion. But since failure to strict observance of religious practices is not that of a big deal in any of them and this could put all of the hairy details of each one to the table, I decided to use a made-up religion. Surely, no actual practicers of Bobism would live very long.

Comment: @Spitemaster And still, that is what many real-world religions actually do.

Comment: @KeizerHarm I am not really a regular visitor to meta and you might just provide me a link. But, what is the problem of "what would you take to a deserted island" questions as long as it is not magical stuff or something like that?

Comment: @Goodies Yes, this question has deep anthropological roots. Religious practices are designed by ancient people and are expected to be easy to be followed. But as soon as you are not on Earth nor anywhere near Earth and special relativity plays a role, following them is extremely hard.

Comment: @VictorStafusa the believers will ignore all these astrophysics considerations.. Bob believes his gods exist, and travel with him. It's not relevant, what planet or time Bob resides in. As long as Bob puts his efforts to comply, Bob will not be forced to commit suicide, he will live on and adjust. When muslims reach a place to live, they will determine very accurately where Mecca is. In the 16th century, muslim settlers prayed to the south-east. Also when they resided in Azerbeydjan, which resides actually *North* of Mecca.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

The outcome is one of the following:

1. Bob was able to identify where they are when *when* they are, and continues with Bobism as normal.
2. Bob was unable to identify where or when they are and received no help from the ship, and committed suicide.
3. The ship provided real or invented navigational and calendrical information to Bob to prevent them committing suicide. Bob will therefore either continue orthodox Bobism, or will unknowingly become a heretic (and is unlikely to ever discover this fact).

There's no room for Neobobism. Bob would probably rather commit suicide than contemplate heresy.

It is possible for outcome (1) to trigger commandment (8), because it turns out that defrosting day was a saturday, and Bob had to work to determine that fact, or it took more than 24 hours to determine the date and as such Bob missed a crucial observance. Outcome (3) can also trigger commandment (8) if Bob later discovers the truth.

If the ship is unable to tell Bob the truth, or is unable to lie in a way that can't be discovered within the lifetime of Bob (or their descendants, if any) then suicide is the most likely outcome. Given that the ship *did* defrost Bob, and probably knows something about their strange beliefs, **this suggests that the ship does in fact know when it is and where it is and is willing to share this information**. Otherwise it would probably have left Bob in stasis forever.

---

(*you only need to read on if you care about how Bob might accomplish outcome 1*)

Over timescales of millions of years of [observed time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time), any equipment that Bob brought with him and kept running during the flight would have broken, malfunctioned, corroded, whatever. Even the finest clocks will not reasonably have remained calibrated, especially in an environment where surprise [galactic cosmic rays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_ray) are a thing, over such a long timescale.

Even if the clocks *had* been maintained, you still need the co-operation of the ship's systems in order to map ship time to Earth-time, dealing with varying time dilations depending on what the ship was doing at any given moment.

You've therefore three choices.

1. The ship's IA has maintained Bob's clocks for them and will provide the necessary information to apply relativistic corrections or is happy to share the details of the shipboard clocks for the sake of Bob's wellbeing, so Bob knows exactly how much time has elapsed on Earth and when things like Ramadan or Saturday will occur next.
2. Bob kept a clock with them in whatever magic stasis-field is used to preserve their body during the flight. Upon reanimation the clock will pick up exactly where it left off. Bob may or may not realise or care.
3. The clock broke aeons ago. Bob has no way of knowing how long they've been paused and the ship won't clarify. Bob must therefore commit suicide immediately. Assuming the ship would like Bob not to kill themselves, it will either share or invent a date and time for them.

So much for time. Lets consider location.

Millions of years of travel at a [lorentz factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor) of >3 means the ship could easily have left the Milky Way. It is probably possible to triangulate the ship's position by careful observation of reasonably distant galaxies, assuming that Bob has access to a powerful telescope and a decent body of astronomical knowledge, and probably a suitable computer to do the hard work of calculation. Such things would have to be purchased ahead of time, and the basic skills for performing the computations learned before the flight. Plausible landmarks might include the [whirlpool galaxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whirlpool_Galaxy), which is visually striking and far enough away that if the ship had a speed below .995c (γ ≈ 10) it might be reasonably expected to still be visible and look more-or-less like it did from Earth when the ship left. Many such landmarks might be needed, in case some were obscured, or distorted by a change in viewpoint, etc.

If the ship travelled at high relativistic speeds (γ ≫ 10) then it is unlikely that Bob will be able to localize their new location given the distances and timescales involved. Without knowing where they are, they cannot hope to know where Earth is, and as such they cannot fulfil commandment (3) and must immediately commit suicide.

Again, assuming the ship would be interested in preventing that from happening, it will presumably either share its navigational information or it will make up something sufficiently plausible that Bob will be satisfied.

Note that [pulsar maps](https://www.pbs.org/the-farthest/science/pulsar-map/) and [multilateration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilateration) are unlikely to be useable over intergalactic distances, unless Bob has access to more information about [extragalactic pulsars](https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/12003) than we have these days. Even then, the pulse rate of pulsars does not decay in a predictable fashion (and many will simply [stop pulsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulsar#Formation,_mechanism,_turn_off) after a few million years), so mapping observed pulsars at the ship's destination to the information tables Bob brought from Earth could be quite impossible unless the ship kept an observation of those pulsars and tracked their pulse rates during the flight, and was prepared to share that information with Bob. If Bob did not know in advance how co-operative the ship was likely to be, they may have brought along multiple location-finding techniques in the hopes that one of them would work.

---

*edit*

From a comment by the OP:

> If [Bob] could see and identify the Milky Way, this probably would make rule 3 way easier.

We don't actually have a good idea of what the Milky Way actually looks like, on account of the fact that bits of it get in the way of other bits of it. It is possible that this remains unknown by the time Bob wakes up. They might be the first person to ever see such a view.

Identifying the Milky Way will have to be inferred from the position and angles of other landmarks (eg. other galaxies or extragalactic pulsars). If the Milky Way *isn't* visible it'll be commandment 3 suicide time, barring an intervention by the ship. If the Milky Way is close enough to take up a significant proportion of the sky, some additional work will be needed to localize Sol within the galactic disc. Which brings me on to:

> What if he discovers that he is still inside the Milky Way?

This might actually be the hardest situation to be in. It may be possible to use astronomy to identify interesting objects within the galaxy... pulsars are problematic due to the whole slow-down-and-stop-pulsing issue, but there are other non-galactic [Messier objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messier_object) in the form of nebulae which might, *maybe* be recogniseable. It may be possible to identify bright, distant stars and map them to stars known from Earth, but this is potentially quite a complex process and Bob would need the assistance of a reasonably capable bit of software to do the hard work and locate Sol (and hence Mecca) before he misses a critical prayer deadline and needed to suicide. As with all the other problems, the ship may provide a suitable *deus ex machina* to keep its meaty cargo alive.

Comment: Hmmm, there is an interesting point in your answer. If the whirlpool galaxy is probably still visible, would Bob be able to tell if he leaved the Milky Way and still see it? If he could see and identify the Milky Way, this probably would make rule 3 way easier. If the Milky Way is nowhere to be found, no deal. What if he discovers that he is still inside the Milky Way?

Comment: @VictorStafusa that's a complex enough question that I'll address it in an edit.

Comment: Oh, and if he awakens on an alien planet with a sky full of perpetual dark clouds, he will probably need to resort to rule 8, right?

Comment: @VictorStafusa it all very much depends on whether the ship is prepared to intervene to keep its cargo alive, whether it knows the appropriate answers and whether it is able to lie convincingly if it does not.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, the question was closed. Your answer is the more complete so far and is the best one that actually tries to solve part of the problem (the Whirlpool Galaxy) instead of just focusing on workarounding it, although still features a lot of that (but this is an important part of the question/answer nevertheless). So, get the green mark.

Comment: @VictorStafusa it is often tricky to phrase a question to please everyone here. A rewrite might cut out some or all of the background material... "_My protagonist is brought out of stasis somewhere in space, millions of years in the future, accompanied by an unhelpful starship AI. They need to know, to the nearest 24 hours, how long they have been in stasis, and where in the galaxy they are. What equipment could they have brought with them to solve this problem? Assume they have travelled at sublight speeds_". Or something. Nitpickers gonna nitpick. I though it was an interesting problem!

Answer (score 10):

Bob simply has to:

Perform no work.

Celebrate Easter and Christmas every day.

Pray in every direction.

Not eat (he will need intravenous nurishment).

Pray all of the time.

Commemorate the Chinese new year every day.

Commemorate Vesak every day.

Comment: Ooh, _technically_ correct following of the commandments, which is the _best_ kind of correct.

Comment: Very clever. Now, I am thinking if praying constantly dancing and shaking the head to everywhere would satisfy rule 3 without needing to know where Mecca is or if this would be a violation of it.

Comment: And when in doubt keep running into any ..anything really until fainting and repeat after waking up.

Comment: I like this. This comment is more directed at the religion than the answer. Does celebrating and the preparations for the celebrations count as work? Ie what happens when your religious holidays fall on the sabbath? Cos by following rules 2 6 7 it will break rule 1 about work on a sabbath.

Comment: Prayer format could evolve to take the form of a whirling dervish dance. You'd face all directions an equal amount of time.

Comment: Does praying facing mecca exclude other praying? Ie just pray in every direction, one of them will fullfill the rule. I'm ednting the answer to include that, seems very much in the spirit of the answer.

Answer (score 7):

## Remove conscious decisions

Each of the rules is incredibly difficult to achieve. Despite Earth time with moons, Ramadan and such only being Earth references, they are for most essential to stay in Earth reference. Timing this without incredibly expensive equipment, probably with extra redundancy, is impossible. Same with gyroscopes, accelerometers and such that would be needed to accurately know where you are to face mekka. Even top of the line expensive equipment is unlikely to survive the long journey.

But there is a loophole to prevent suicide. I kniw it's only written to allow the person to adhere to Bobism while frozen, but we can use the 'unconscious' or 'unable to make conscious decisions' clause. At first I was going to suggest a medical coma for 80 years and have the ship take care of you intravenously. This can't solve hygene though, likely killing Bob before his target of 80 years.

That is needed is a form of lobotomy, damagingbthe frontal lobe is a specific way. This way you can remove conscious decision making, while still having a person able to do routine tasks. Self lobotomy can still result in death, giving rule 8 a chance. If conscious decisions are still possible he'll have to try again. Damage to the frontal lobe should only remove planning and conscious decisions, at least how we know it, and leave things like motor skills and primary drives like hunger in tact.

I think this is the best possible option to adhere to Bobism. As there is no way to follow rules 1-7 with any accuracy, you can try rule 9. Failing rule 9 rule number 8 will automatically go in effect. Rule 9 is no guarantee Bob will live to 80+, but does give a (small) chance if primary drives might still allow for food and hygiene to be fulfilled. Even if there's some conscious decisions Bob has no way to consciously fulfill Bobism in that state.

Comment: Your answer is simply completely insane! I like it!

Comment: Does someone ever performed a successful self-lobotomy? Does someone ever tried do that?

Comment: Although this is solvable if a million dollar lobotomatic™ machine is his equipment...

Comment: @VictorStafusa there are case reports. The brain is still not understood enough to do the lobotomy accurately, though a normal lobotomy could already satisfy clause 9 if read in some ways. A small machine can certainly help, but otherwise a hammer and chisel might be enough. Still big risk of death and not sure if the lombotomised person might at some point simply neglect him or herself. Still a better chance than trying to pray all waking hours and not miss one celebration/prayer/direction during a conscious hour. Especially if you're randomly spinning.....

Answer (score 5):

### Just redefine the time in the local system

Trying to keep to earth time is a fools errand at best and utterly ridiculous at worst. You will get a decent fix on the time with radioactive decay, the CMB and the movement of stars. But this will only ever get you so far and there is a better solution.

Parts of the commandments are based on cyclical events, just take the local cycles and adjust your time keeping. Take the local year (revolution around the star) and place the holy days at the appropriate fraction of the year. In some cases you might have to get very creative. Binary star systems create issues regarding noon. Noon is a place on a tidally locked world, not a time. Short orbital periods make make you life too busy. Mecca is a tricky one, maybe you pick a certain direction and stick with it, maybe you pray towards where Sol will rise above the horizon.

Alternatively just define a random and pleasant cycle onboard the vessel and run with it. These events are based on Earths cycles and the prophets would have used local cycles in a different environment.

Addendum: Since he has 1000 kg cargo allowance, how about one (or more) spouses as well as a number of fertilised eggs. That would surely help with the madness issue and give his religion a stronger purpose.

Comment: What if he awakens in interstellar or even intergalactic space? What if he awakens in a planet with a perpetually dark-clouded sky?

Comment: @VictorStafusa In the first two cases the CMB and some math  in combination with an accelerometer and an atomic clock, which ran from the beginning of the journey should do nicely. In the latter case you just have to scratch the CMB option. It doesn't matter, time is (partially) rather arbitrarily defined anyway. One of it has a celestial basis, but weeks, minutes and hours?

Answer (score 5):

Do we have classic 60s SF or current-day SF? Oh well, it will work in both cases!

## Ask the Computer

"Computer, what day is it?"

"Computer, what time is it?"

"Computer, do I have to obey a religious restriction the next hour?"

Basically, we outsource the tracking of time to an outside entity.

## Contradiction

You say:

> The IA don't ever talk to Bob or listen him and is entirely autonomous. It treats him like most people would treat a pet fish in an aquarium.

But if it is not merely a SF computer, but an IA, it would be aware of Bob's religious restrictions and react accordingly. Because IA is not quite interested in Bob dying and the interaction is on the level of throwing in some fish food.

Answer (score 5):

**Leap Seconds make it impossible to know what hour (or day) it is.**

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second

> A leap second is a one-second adjustment that is occasionally applied to Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), to accommodate the difference between precise time (International Atomic Time (TAI), as measured by atomic clocks) and imprecise observed solar time (UT1), which varies due to irregularities and long-term slowdown in the Earth's rotation.

> Between 1972 and 2020, a leap second has been inserted about every 21 months, on average. However, the spacing is quite irregular and apparently increasing: there were no leap seconds in the six-year interval between January 1, 1999 and December 31, 2004, but there were nine leap seconds in the eight years 1972–1979.

Over the course of a single million of years of travel, the Earth will have added an unknown number of leap seconds to its calendar. Probably more than 14 hours, probably less than 140 hours (5+ days). Multiply that uncertainty by the number of millions of years in transit.

So the ship's atomic-clock tracking of Earth's seconds might remain accurate. But since the number of leap seconds is unknowable, there's no way for the travelers to observe or deduce which set of seconds corresponds to a specific Earth hour (Rules #4 and #5) or day or day-of week (Rule #1).

Therefore, Rule #8 applies.

Of course, Earth could transmit that calendar information to the colonists...but then Bob would easily know the direction and distance of Earth and the proper calendar without having to figure it all out himself, which seems to violate the spirit of the question.

Answer (score 4):

### Time

**Religions allow for circular reasoning, so Bob wakes up on a saturday**

Week days are easy. Bob could determine it, even in space. Bob has always observed the rules. That is because the gods wanted him to do that. He has always observed the rules correctly, and there is no reason for Bob to assume he could decide anything else.

Belief systems are an ideal reference. There's a day prescribed Bob *can't be allowed to work*. As Bob will certainly NOT be able to work after waking up, he'll designate the day he woke up as a Saturday and he will regard one day length as the time it took him to recover and get to work. Daily and weekly religious obligations can now be fulfilled.

**Bob finds a livable planet with 1 moon**

To be able to observe any other religious rule, Bob needs day and night, as well as *both* moon calendar and sun calendar, the gods would make him wake up on a planet with a moon, of course. What's the purpose of believing things when they don't come true ?

[image]

Chinese New Year is on a crescent new moon and Ramadan is on a crescent new moon. The moon *must* be there. Only one moon.

In the Gregorian calendar, the Chinese New Year begins at the new moon that falls between 21 January and 20 Februari, that is: the second month of winter.

**Bob waits for a new moon**

The first and second crescent moon Bob will observe, determine 12 candidate moments for Ramadan and Chinese new year.

**Bob waits for winter solstice**

To find the day of Chinese new year, Bob needs to find the second month of winter. Bob needs to determine the seasons. Bob will need to observe when the sun reaches its highest point in the day.. and when it reaches its lowest point in the day..

Bob may celebrate Christmas 4 days later. He'll divide the intervals in 6 months each. The proper time for Chinese New Year will be the first new moon in the 2nd month after the winter solstice. After a year, Bob will know when to observe important days.

**Bob celebrates new year 0 AE (Ante Exsuscito)**

[image]

The hours and minutes are easy. At summer solstice, Bob sets sunrise at 4:00 AM and sunset at 10:00 PM, the hours evenly spread between these times.

**Ramadan and Easter require a sign from the heavens**

As opposed to Chinese New Year, the start of Ramadan may occur in any (sun-year) season. In order to determine Ramadan, the moon year should be counted in the Islamic months since the prophet's birth. The gods will have to decide the first Ramadan for Bob, giving Bob a sign at some time after arrival. The issue is, Bob does not know how much time he was underways. The Islamic moon year calendar cannot be observed, there is no continuous time frame. The same issue would be Easter day, which relies on an analytical method using Gregorian calendar days.

### Place

**Place requires a sign from the heavens**

When Bob saw the new (or near-new) moon in the sky, he realized the gods must have played a role determining his faith. He will be convinced the gods traveled with him.. providing him with a planet having a moon the same apparent size as Earth's moon.. that can't be a coincidence, it must be how the gods prepared things for him..

[image]

Bob's location is unknown. But the gods, nor Bob are aware of modern astrophysics, or relativistic uncertainties. That makes it a lot easier to determine where Mekka on planet Earth is ! When bob arrives at his god-given destination, a divine manifestation will happen. It will point Bob's attention to a specific heavenly phenomenon.. and Bob will notice he'll have the urge to pray in *that* direction.

[image]

Comment: Great answer, really. But what if there is no Moon or even no Sun?

Comment: @VictorStafusa there are too many rules Bob has to follow that relate to the moon and the moon calandar. After some 3 weeks, Bob will realize he can't possibly fulfill his religious duties. He will miss the moon. After a while, he'll dream he sees the moon. But these dreams fade away, memories of Earth fade away, making Bob very unhappy on this planet. He may consider fulfilling the ultimate religious duty, as you devised it in your system. It may be an interesting part of the story, this is a "devil's choice" for Bobbists: when dead, they can't perform any duty at all.

Answer (score 3):

Frame challenge about Bobism practised on Earth *before* Bob left on journey:

- People waking up from a coma may have muscle atrophy or further paralysis.
- People regaining consciousness from fainting/deep sleep may have temporary mental confusion/brain fog over their situation.
- People struck by a natural disaster eg an earthquake and stuck under a collapsed building can't move and turn to face a particular direction.
- What about those unable to commit suicide themselves. Is assisted suicide allowed? If not, how do they punish themselves for breaking rule8 repeatedly?

Are they expected to follow rules 1-7 and ultimately 8 the minute they wake up?  Even if they woke up at 11.58 am and miss the noon day pray as they were still struggling with removing all the deep sleep paraphernalia/collapsed building on top of them?

As rule 9 allows for those original exceptions in the first place, it must also allow for the related realities that occur after those exceptions.

Therefore I propose rule 10 as a *continuation* of rule 9. Wording up to you.

Along the lines of all effort must be made to follow rules 1-7  as soon as reasonably possible after regaining consciousness. Pray twice on Sunday for a month as penance for the lost time!

Edit: Addressing these issues in the rules before Bob leaves would possibly give Bob a buffer of some sort, once he wakes up lost in a million years, before he is expected to follow rule8. Gives him time to calculate all religious requirements as provided by any other answers.

Comment: He might be a bit confused in the moment he wakes up. But in say, 5 minutes, he will surely be able to make conscious decisions. And, he was not kept in coma in the men time. He is frozen up, like Han Solo ws in Star Wars (will edit that into the question for clarification), so no muscle atrophy or paralysis once wake up.

Comment: Sorry should have clarified the frame challenge. It's not about when Bob wakes up in a million years  it's about the practicality of Bobism as practised before he left! Addressing these issues before he leaves, _gives you time_ to calculate time/location/directions later!

Comment: I edited the question for clarification. Is it better now?

Comment: I do realise Bob won't be incapacitated mentally. I'm saying there is a natural error in the rules of religion itself that would have been addressed by actual practioners long before Bob even left! Unless this is a religion that Bob made up himself that no one else knows about and he just didn't think of these possibilities before adding rule8.

Comment: Addressing those possibilities in your religions rules may give you some leeway to allow Bob a little breathing room in working out where in the universe he is before he is made to follow rule 8 for breaking any of rules1-7.

Comment: *"I'm saying there is a natural error in the rules of religion itself"* - Well, you could say that exactly thing about EVERY religion on Earth! And even on atheism!

Comment: Lol. Well then Bob is screwed!

Answer (score 3):

## Trick Bob

1. Bob outsources this problem and contracts a private firm to provide him with equipment that he can bring that will allow him to fully live his religion after he is unfrozen.
2. The private firm realizes the impossibility of doing this task legitimately, and instead decides to cheat, as Bob will never know the difference.
3. They provide Bob with equipment that Bob can set up once he gets to wherever he goes that will give him completely accurate notifications and alarms for all of his religious observances.
4. They tell him there is a risk that he'll set up the equipment on a Saturday and have to kill himself, but really there are measures to ensure that the equipment never actually does this after being turned on.
5. They explain to bob that this equipment is incredibly complex, and that he would need to get multiple PhD's in several fields to understand how it actually works, so there's no way he can really get it within the time frame. And they give a convincing but false rough explanation with a lot of technical terms that they know Bob won't really understand.
6. The equipment is designed in such a way as to obscure how it actually works so that Bob never finds out, and to provide internally consistent notifications as to not ever provide any suspicion that it may be inaccurate.

When Bob turns it on, and after a few minutes of "gathering stellar data" and "calculating" it says it is Tuesday at 4:33 am, and there is an arrow pointing toward Mecca, which always points to the same location in the night sky between two visible stars. There are also displayed countdowns to the next observance of each type. Bob believes, and observes his religion as per the equipment's instructions. Bob lives to a ripe old age and dies of natural causes. The private firm has been successful in its mandate to keep Bob alive after defrosting.

Bob goes to his version of the afterlife and finds out he's been tricked and goes to his version of torment. Sorry Bob, but at least you were happy while you lived.

Comment: I really like your answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Bob has with him a mains-powered and mains-clocked clock/calendar/moon phase display.

Since by the time that he wakes (millions of years local at > .95C's time dilation, i.e. 32+ years on earth per local subjective year), Earth won't be detectable, and might as well not exist, time will be arbitrary.  So, the clock is set to a default time of the time at which Bob was put to sleep plus the time it takes for him to be put to sleep and to wake up, retrieve the clock and plug it in.

The AI, while not programmed to communicate with Bob, must still keep Bob as healthy and happy as possible with what it was given.  To that end, when Bob wakes, it will match the shipboard time of day to that at which Bob entered cryostasis, in order to minimise Bob's discomfort as a result of temporal discontinuities.

Bob wakes, plugs in his clock, and is reassured by the display of the time, date and moon phase, knowing that he can practise Bobism's time-dependent rituals at what will feel like the correct time.  Bob is defining shipboard time by his personal experiences.  *Not* being aware of the passage of time while frozen as opposed to *being* aware of the passage of time while merely asleep, means that time spent frozen can be effectively ignored.

The ship's power-grade 60Hz AC power is as good a clock as any you're likely to find.  Clocks have used AC power as a timing source for many years, and are more accurate than most clocks containing their own timing source.

As for facing Mecca, that's simple.  Bob faces the rear of the ship, since Mecca is on Earth, and that's where the ship has come from, and therefore is what the rear of the ship is pointing at.  The ship may rotate around its axis, but rotating ships typically rotate around their long axis, with its main engines at the rear, at one end of the axis of rotation.  Otherwise, the engines would be much more difficult to control during long burns.

Sure, these are rationalizations, but religious people appear able to rationalise quite easily, especially when it feels right.

Comment: *"Bob faces the rear of the ship"* - Supposing that it not landed on some planet and supposing that it traveled in a roughly straight trajectory.

Answer (score 1):

## Bob has already committed suicide.

According to rule 1 "No work whatsoever should be performed on Saturdays". If we define work as any physical or mental effort done in order to achieve a particular objective, Bob would be breaking rule 1 by following rules 2-7 as they are work (effort) put into pleasing God. As I see it:

- Bob has committed suicide (not in a Saturday, of course)
- Bob is living in hypocrisy and, therefore, after arriving he would continue practicing his religion in any way he wants.